# QDirIterator изменить dir

Tags: c++, qt

Есть функция `getFileInfo`

```
bool getFileInfo (QDir dir, QFileInfo *tmp) {
    QDirIterator it(dir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        *tmp = it.fileInfo();
        it.next();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

которая принимает путь к файлам и возвращает один файл по ссылке.

Идёт вызов функции для получения всех файлов папки

```
while (getFileInfo(dir1, &fileInfo)){
    ...
}
while (getFileInfo(dir2, &fileInfo)){
    ...
}
```

Сейчас функция уйдёт в бесконечный цикл, однако, если добавить static для QDirIterator, то нельзя будет указывать другой путь к файлам.

Как организовать нормальную работу с QDirIterator?

P.S. идеальный вариант - объявить пустой QDirIterator в классе, и как-нибудь изменять его перед

```
while (getFileInfo(dir1, &fileInfo)){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Я очень рад, что вы умеете кодить лучше человека, который первый день начал разбираться в Qt, но прошу без оскорблений указать на мои ошибки.

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать просто итератор напрямую вместо этой функции?

Comment: Если вы хотите сохранять состояние итератора и не хотите напрямую использовать итератор, то напишите объект-функцию и вызывайте его оператор функцию.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow действительно. Слишком сильно зациклился на этой *дебильной* отдельной функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно напрямую в цикле использовать итератор. То есть вместо функции просто используйте цикл в ее теле.

Другой подход - это создать объект функции.

Например,

```
class GetFileInfo
{
protected:
    QDirIterator it;

public:
    GetFileInfo ( const QDir &dir ) : it(dir, QDirIterator::Subdirectories)
    {
    }

    bool operator ()( QFileInfo *tmp )
    {
        bool success = it.hasNext();

        if ( success )
        {
            it.next();
            *tmp = it.fileInfo();
        }

        return success;
    }
};
```

И использовать его как

```
GetFileInfo fileinfo( dir );

while ( fileInfo( &tmp ) )
{
    //...
}
```

Можно также добавить явную функцию преобразования объекта класса в тип bool.

Тогда можно будет писать

```
while ( fileInfo )
{
    fileInfo( &tmp );
    //...
}
```

Так как я не имел дело с Qt, то возможно есть неточности в определении объекта функции. Тем не менее он демонстрирует подход к решению задачи.

Comment: Вариант с классом не сработает, ибо QDirIterator очень капризная штука, из-за чего и пришлось спрашивать. Но вариант с использованием QDirIterator без отдельной функции более чем подходит.

Comment: @Виталий Я не вижу, в чем заключается его "капризность", которая мешает поместить его в объект функции.

Comment: Чтобы не было ошибок компиляции, нужно написать `QDirIterator it = ""`, что для меня не было так очевидно.

Comment: @Виталий Этого не нужно делать, если вы напишите конструктор, как в моем примере.